# Delphi "case of" expression expects constant

Tags: delphi, case-statement

I was porting my communication library written in C to Delphi which uses **#define** and "**switch case**" for one of the function.

I have translated them by using "**const**" and "**case of**" in Delphi.

But Delphi compiler complains by saying that "[dcc32 Error] Comm.Meter.pas(76): **E2026 Constant expression expected**".

As long as I see, there is nothing non-constant. Why is this? And what is the proper solution?

```
Const
  COM_SOH: Byte = 1;    // Start of Header
  COM_STX: Byte = 2;    // Start of Text
  COM_ETX: Byte = 3;    // End of Text
  COM_ACK: Byte = 6;    // Acknowledge
  COM_NACK: Byte = 21;  // Not acknowledge
  COM_CR: Byte = 13;
  COM_LF: Byte = 10;
  COM_DIV: Byte = 47;

function test_case(const ch: byte): Int32;
begin
  Result := 0;

  case ch of
    COM_DIV:
    begin
      Result := ch + 1;
    end;

    COM_ACK:
    begin
      Result := ch + 2;
    end;

    COM_NACK:
    begin
      Result := ch + 3;
    end;

    COM_STX:
    begin
      Result := ch + 4;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your `Const`s are actually `typed constants` (because of the `: Byte`, and you can't have those as the selectors in `Case` statements,

Comment: You can read more about `true constants` and `typed constants` in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declared_Constants)

Comment: you must use Const  COM_SOH= 1;